# Not able to get correct document/window width/height ratios after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code gives correct ratios when we manually resize the window. But after loading window it gives ratios as 1 even if I set window size to give value more than 1. I forced reset for dummy control to recalculate value but to no avail.

Not able to figure out where I am going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
 var widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();

$("#dummy").resize(function(){
  heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
  widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();
  console.log(heightRatio + ": " + widthRatio);
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
  widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();
  console.log(heightRatio + ": " + widthRatio);
});
$("#dummy").resize();
});
```

Update: I made a simple testpage where this code seemed to work as expected.

Update2:
In my page I am loading content in index.html using load function as follows:

```
$("#container").load("pages/orders/_orders.html");
```

I tried putting the ration capture code after the above line. But still not working.

Update 3:
Sandbox code to replicate the issue. Look at the jump in WR value from initial value 1, if you resize the width even a tiny bit.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    #one{
      display: grid;
      border: 1px black solid;
      width: 600px;
      height: 1200px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    #second{
      border: 1px black solid;
      width: 3000px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    #container{
      display: grid;
      top: 200px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="one">
      <div id="dummy"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script>

    //$("#container").load("_test.html");
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").load("_test.html");
    var heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
    var widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();

    $("#dummy").resize(function(){
      heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
      widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();
      console.log("from Dummy HR: " + heightRatio + "   WR: " + widthRatio);
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
      heightRatio = $(document).height()/$(window).height();
      widthRatio = $(document).width()/$(window).width();
      console.log("From Window HR:"+ heightRatio + " WR: " + widthRatio);
    });
    $("#dummy").resize();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**_test.html**

```
<div id="second">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you need these items to resize immediately after the page loads?

Comment: @Mike I am resizing dummy to get ratios immediately as a hack.